# Ubuntu-sdk apps on other distros

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, debian

So I have just made my first Ubuntu sdk application in QML.

I wonder,on a scale from 1-10 how friendly is the Ubuntu SDK to other Linux distributions?
How much possible is it to run the apps I create with the ubuntu SDK on other Linux distributions?I understand that it is probably easier on Ubuntu or even Debian based distributions,but probably tougher on .rpm based distributions.

However I want to listen to some opinions.